# ¿Como puedo bloquear que en mi servidor de node js aparezca el codigo de mi recaptcha?

Tags: nodejs, formularios, angular10

Descripcion:
Tengo un servidor para el envio de un correo en angular y mi servidor hecho con node js pero al enviar mis datos en la consola en el inspector del navegador me carga el dato del recaptcha y lo que quiero es ocultarlo  para que no aparezca por si alguien entra al inspector y checa esos datos no quiero que los vea ese requisito me lo piden en mi trabajo me ayudarian mucho ya que estoy por entregar mi proyecto gracias.

1.Servidor

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//cambio 1
const configMensaje = require('./configMensaje');


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Configurar cabeceras y cors
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});


app.post('/form', (req, res) => {
//cambio 2
configMensaje(req.body);//estara almacenado un objeto al modulo llmado body parser
res.status(200).send();
console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server running');
})
```

2.Mensaje al correo

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

module.exports = (form) => {//se ecporta module.express para ser utilizada en el archivo principal
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'example@gmail.com',//mi correo
            pass: 'password',
        }
    });

    const mailOptions = {
        from: `"${form.Name}" "${form.Surnames}" <${form.email}>`, //remitente
        to: `example@gmail.com`,//correo de destino
        subject: form.Affair,//asunto del mensaje
        //cuerpo del mensaje
        html:`
        <strong>Nombre:</strong> ${form.Name} <br/>
        <strong>Apellidos:</strong> ${form.Surnames} <br/>
        <strong>Asunto:</strong> ${form.Affair} <br/>
        <strong>E-mail:</strong> ${form.email} <br/>
        <strong>Mensaje:</strong> ${form.txt}
        `
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {//se encarga de enviar nuestro mensaje y retornar un valor ya sea un error on el objeto del mensaje
        if(err)
        console.log(err)
        else
        console.log(info)
    });
}
```

3.validaciones y impresion de los datos en consola

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MessageService } from '../services/message.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  siteKey: string;
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, public _MessageService: MessageService) {
    this.siteKey = '84djnds3498hgg874bdfsidasdsn4859394390nd';

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Name: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      ],
      Surnames: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
      ],
      email: ['', Validators.email],
      Affair: ['', Validators.required],
      txt: ['', Validators.required],
      RES: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  saveData() {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }

  contactForm(form) {
    this._MessageService.sendMessage(form).subscribe(() => {
      Swal.fire('Formulario enviado exitosamente');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué dato? ¿Cómo sale? ¿Dónde sale? La pregunta que me hago es, ¿Porqué tienes el valor de `sitekey` en el front de tu aplicación?

Comment: El dato de la sitekey,sale en mi servidor de nodejs,el sitekey no esta en mi front en donde esta el sitekey es el back de mi componente de angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hasta donde tengo entendido eso no es posible, te intento dar algo de luz:

El servicio de google recaptcha funciona por lado del cliente y por lado del servidor, ambas partes de modo obligatorio. Esto se debe a que cuando un visitante entra en tu web, se carga un valor para el input recaptcha_respone, el cual tiene que ir asociado a tu cuenta.
Ese valor lo almacena google y le asigna un valor de 0 a 1 según el análisis que hagan, después de hacer el submit del formulario, desde tu backend accedes a esos "resultados" para ver si es un bot o no.

No se puede dejar en blanco la key debido a que no lo asociaría a tu cuenta y desde el backend y no podrías tener la respuesta en ningún momento.

Tener esa clave, es lo que realmente asegura que el formulario no es malicioso, si no existiese, se podría clonar un formulario idéntico en otra web y google te podría responder que el formulario no es malicioso.

De todos modos, piensa que estas keys únicamente se pueden usar en los dominios que tengas configurados en la admin console, aunque copien esa key y la inserten en otra web nunca podrán hacerte un submit desde otro lado.

Nota: si que hay servicios como la web de https://2captcha.com/ que se dedican a mandar el challenge a una persona para que lo resuelva y devuelven la respuesta, es la única manera de automatización que se me ocurre, pero bots en ningún momento podrán acceder.

Se que no he respondido a la duda como tal, pero espero que de algo te valga la respuesta o si se te ocurre como hacerlo, espero que lo compartas!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tienes razon,me abriste los ojos thanks